# Does overspray get on the ceiling when spraying interior wall?

Tags: painting

I have a freshly painted ceiling in a 1200 sq ft, new construction home.  I have access to a medium-quality airless paint sprayer.  I have some 4' rolls of plastic sheeting that I can tape up on the ceiling to get 4' of the ceiling perimeter masked off (don't have the roll hand gun device but just hand taping it for now).  My two concerns are: 1.) Does the spray leave a heavy overspray that can float to the ceiling? Especially when I start dark colors?  I realize this depends on the method of spraying, but in general I want to know if I am wasting my time with masking and should start rolling right now or if it is worth masking off the perimeter and that the 4' would be sufficient?  I have to mask the ceiling edge anyway with tape, but the 4' plastic takes 4 to 5 times longer to install when I account for unfolding it and taping it 4' back from the walls and when dealing with temporary 200W incandescent ceiling lights.  My windows are already masked off from spraying texture at least.

I have about 4 different colors in the whole house and it's about 1200 square feet for size.  My texture is knockdown and it's not very deep so rolling it should not be a lot of extra work in terms of heavy textures.

Answer (score 1):

You will definitely need to mask off the ceiling, over spray gets everywhere.....

Comment: Jack, do you mean the entirety of the ceiling, then? Or just the 4' perimeter?

Comment: The 4' will do it

Comment: Do cover the wall outlets, spray inside them is difficult for the electricians.

Comment: @Jack it turns all your wires into neutrals.